# Is it true that Silverlight will not support OpenGL?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, silverlight, opengl

Is there any way to implement the OpenGL on the Silverlight? We need to create a web browser application to load an OpenGL 3D image  and to perform rotation and zoom functionality. We can easily load the OpenGL component in a WPF windows application. But it is not allowing to load the OpenGL in to a Silverlight application.

If Silverlight doesn't support OpenGL, what is be the best choice to create the web application with OpenGL 3D?

Comment: Why do you want to use OpenGL *specifically*? Silverlight has 3D rendering routines. Just use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silverlight does not support it, nor will it in the future (Silverlight is discontinued!). Instead for cross-platform graphics you could go with WebGL, but it isn't implemented in every browser yet but seems to be the future.

To clarify, Internet Explorer does not support it (Big shocker!) while Safari and Opera do have it, but need it to be enabled by the user prior to it working. There is no other true cross-platform way to deploy OpenGL on the web at this point.