# mono/moonlight + opengl?

Tags: c#, opengl, mono

Is it possible to run opengl code in moonlight/silverlight?

I know that WPF can be hardware accelerated and moonlight supports hardware acceleration, but I get the impression that isn't necessarily the same as having the hardware access to being able to use a full fledged opengl framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Moonlight is [somewhat dead](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/05/Miguel-Moonlight), so I wouldn't spend much effort in making this work.

In any case I do not believe it is possible to run [OpenGL code with Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371736/is-it-true-that-silverlight-will-not-support-opengl), and as far as I can remember no effort was done to support it separately with Moonlight either.

Comment: Thanks for that info.  Wasted effort was exactly what I wanted to avoid.  I noticed the answerer in that post says there's no current cross platform way to deploy OpenGL across the web, but I've seen Java applets(or what I believe are Java applets) like Minecraft running 3D in a browser.  Not sure if that's OpenGL for sure though.  Of course there is Unity as well.  But was hoping to leverage my experience with C# so I wouldn't both be learning a 3D framework and a new language at the same time.

Comment: Unity uses Mono for scripting so you could use C# if you write apps using the Unity engine.